# the meaning of 'a transfer' in this notice: You can't get HIV from touching a seat, a pole, a transfer, or someone's hand

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "touching a transfer" when a notice is given about HIV, for instance?

Comment: where have you looked on your own for an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to have any certainty without more context, but based on the few words provided it seems that public transportation is being discussed, and a "transfer" is a sort of ticket between different "legs" of the journey.

Answer (score 0):

items such as utensils etc... Items a HIV infected individual has also handled or touched.

much more here:  http://www.thewellproject.org/hiv-information/hiv-transmission

Comment: Thank you very much. This does makes sense. Actually, I read the notice inside the subway train.